# "Could not support development" xCode 4.4.1 to iTouch 3rd Gen (4.2.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-4.2, xcode4.4

I'm trying to use an old 3rd Gen iTouch (running iOS 4.2.1) as a development device using the latest xCode.

I'm registered/paid for the Apple Dev Program and got a valid provisioning profile on the iTouch.

However, the xCode Organizer stubbornly states "Could not support development". The iOS deployment target is set to 4.2.

arm6 and arm7 are both listed under valid architectures.

I creeped round the Net a bit, but most fixes seem to just have me rebooting/closing/reopening xcode/itunes/my mbp or any combination of those.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you gone into Preferences>Downloads and installed the relevant device support package?

Comment: Yup; installed both the 4.0 and 3.0 Device Debugging Support packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrounged around a couple of days and finally figured it out. Had to install the 4.0 Device Debugging Support package(s).

This brought me to another error ("Can't find directory xxx ... x002"). Stalked round the Net and had to go into Library/Development/iOS/... and add some configuration files to "/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches".

Did that, restarted xCode, and my iTouch finally turned green.

Now I just need to figure out how to get it to appear under Run>Scheme...Got valid provisioning files, deployment target set to 4.2, Base SDK is on iOS latest...time for some more net creeping.

*sigh*